# disable item in listview android java

Tags: java, android, listview

Im trying disable some items in listview , but cant to do it. 
I have Array of booleans

```
private boolean[] array; //10 items all false, and some of them true
```

in code im trying

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
 if(!array[i]){
   listview.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
 }
}
```

but im always got **nullpointerexception** on string "listview.getChildAt()"
if write like

> if(listview.getChildAt(i)!=null){    //do code here }

than i see what no entrance to string "getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false)"
im little not understand about getChildAt but i was thinking its way where i can get items by position. Any one can help me how to do it?
**adapter for list view**

```
public class LevelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

      public LevelAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> le, ArrayList<Integer> co, boolean[] bools) {
        super(context, R.layout.listviewitem, le);
        this.context = context;
        this.l = le;
        this.s = co;
        this.boolStates = bools;


    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewitem, null, true);

        tvL = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.l);
        tvC = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.s);
        tvL.setText(""+l.get(position));
        tvCt.setText(""+s.get(position) + "/3");



        return rowView;
    }

}
```

regards , Peter.

**SOLUTION**

in adapter check

```
if(lvl[position]==false){
            rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewitemdisabled, null, true);

            rowView.setEnabled(false);

        }else
        {
            rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewitem, null, true);
        }
```

and when click on

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (view.isEnabled()) {
                     // do our code here
```

thanks for this easy solution

Comment: How are you using adapter with this listview?

Comment: yea sorry, i will add it now to cde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set enabled state in your adapter.

`rowView.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: i was try it , but items still active and i can press them :(

Answer (score 0):

Use Adapter approach.
Create an adapter and a viewHolder and in OnBind method just get that item of list and disable it.
send value to the adapter using method and notify the adapter about change.